# EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject() returning false in MouseEnter Event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting a weird problem , i have to block mouseEnter/Exit Event when there any  NGUI involve between mouse and the object. For this reason I am using this

```
public void OnMouseEnter()
{
    if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
    {
        renderer.material.color = highlighColour;
    }
}
```

but `EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()` is always false. While the same code snippet is work the Unity Canvas correctly.

Comment: How is IsPointerOverGameObject() implemented?

Comment: Two questions 1) Is the object moved to the Front? 2) Did you add the event to the correct GUI object?

Comment: I see you're using `OnMouseEnter` so this from the official docs might be applicable: **Note that for touch, IsPointerOverGameObject should be used with OnMouseDown() or Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) or Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began.**

Comment: Thanks all, i have identified the problem. we have to use `UICamera.isOverUI`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have identified the problem, for the NGUI you have to use `UICamera.isOverU`

```
 public void OnMouseEnter()
    {

        //if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
        if (!UICamera.isOverUI)
        {
            renderer.material.color = highlighColour;
        }
    }
```